# Django rendering a number as a 5-stars rating

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm building a rating system for my website. It's currently working well but I would like to improve the esthetical aspect of the system. I would like to be able to take the rating from the database and display it as a 5-stars rating. Also, if it's not overly complicated, I would like to be able to click on stars to record the rating in the database, rather than writing a number.

I'm quite new to web development. In particular, I have no experience with javascript (I only did tutorials found on internet), which I think is required to implement the functionality I'm searching for, so please gives me a little example with your response in order to make me able to understand.

For rendering the rating as stars, I have no idea how to do it. For recording the rating as stars, I thought about two solutions :

1) Using [django star-ratings](https://pypi.org/project/django-star-ratings/) but I don't think I have the capabilities required to understand how it works. I already made a post to ask for help and examples about this app but I received no help so I guess I should forget this.

2) Using a form with some appropriate widget to render an IntegerInput as a 5-stars rating.

For the second solution, I already have the code, I now need a widget to replace `'Stars'` in the code below but I'm not sure how to do it. Can someone help me ?

models.py

```
class Avis(models.Model):
    note = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
class AvisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avis
        fields = ['note']
        widgets = {'note': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'Stars'})}
        labels = {'note': 'Note /5'}
```

hmtl for recording

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
  <div class="fieldWrapper form-group">
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase font- 
  weight-bold mb-2" value="Envoyer mon avis" />
</form>
```

hmtl for displaying

```
{{ avis.note }}
```

Thanks in advance !

EDIT (my code so far for the ratings storing) :
views.py

```
def avis(request, id): # view for displaying and storing the form
    commande = get_object_or_404(Commande, id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AvisForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            avis = form.save(commit = False)
            avis.commande = commande
            avis.save()
            commande.has_avis = True
            commande.save()
            if commande.plat.chef.nb_avis==0:
                commande.plat.chef.rating = avis.note
            else:
                commande.plat.chef.rating = (commande.plat.chef.rating*commande.plat.chef.nb_avis + avis.note)/(commande.plat.chef.nb_avis + 1)
            commande.plat.chef.nb_avis += 1
            commande.plat.chef.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Votre avis a été correctement envoyé !')
            return redirect(mes_commandes)
    else:
        form = AvisForm()

    return render(request, 'actualites/avis.html', locals())

def avis2(request, id): # view for recording the rating
    avis = get_object_or_404(Avis, id=id)
    rating = request.POST.get('rating')
    avis.note = rating
    avis.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Votre avis a été correctement envoyé !')
    return redirect(mes_commandes)
```

html

```
 <form method="post" action="">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% for field in form %}
   <div class="fieldWrapper form-group">
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {{ field }}
   </div>
   {% endfor %}
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-login text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-2" value="Envoyer mon avis" />
</form>
<div class="rating rating2">
  <a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars" data-value="5">★</a>
  <a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars" data-value="4">★</a>
  <a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars" data-value="3">★</a>
  <a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars" data-value="2">★</a>
  <a href="#1" title="Give 1 star" data-value="1">★</a>
</div>

<script>
  $(".rating a").on('click', function(e){
    let value = $(this).data('value');
     $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'avis2' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'rating': value},
        success: function (d){
         // some processing
        }
     })
  });
</script>
```

forms.py

```
class AvisForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Avis
        fields = ['commentaire']
        widgets = {'commentaire': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the documentation on `django-star-ratings` on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/django-star-ratings/)?

Comment: There aren't examples and little or no instructions on how to actually use the app to record and display ratings in the template. Maybe I'm supposed to look into the code to understand, which I did, but I'm not good enough with Django to understand this. A user gave me below a easier way to do what I want, thanks for your comment anyway

Comment: Do you know how to get the rating of individual user in the django star rating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to answer your both of the question. For getting the rating, your can render stars and add a JS click event to that. 
Code (HTML, CSS) source: https://codepen.io/GeoffreyCrofte/pen/jEkBL

```js
$(".rating a").on('click', function(e){
 let value = $(this).data('value');
   $.ajax({
      url: "some_url",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'rating': value},
      success: function (d){
       // some processing
      }
   })
});
```

```css
.rating {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  font-size: 45px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.rating input {
  float: right;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.rating a, 
.rating label {
   float:right;
   color: #aaa;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition: color .4s;
   -moz-transition: color .4s;
   -o-transition: color .4s;
   transition: color .4s;
  }
.rating label:hover ~ label,
.rating input:focus ~ label,
.rating label:hover,
  .rating a:hover,
  .rating a:hover ~ a,
  .rating a:focus,
  .rating a:focus ~ a  {
   color: orange;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  .rating2 {
   direction: rtl;
  }
  .rating2 a {
   float:none
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating rating2">
 <a href="#5" title="Give 5 stars" data-value="5">★</a>
 <a href="#4" title="Give 4 stars" data-value="4">★</a>
 <a href="#3" title="Give 3 stars" data-value="3">★</a>
 <a href="#2" title="Give 2 stars" data-value="2">★</a>
 <a href="#1" title="Give 1 star" data-value="1">★</a>
</div>
```

For Rendering the rating, you need to calculate the value first. You need to determine the number of person who rated 5, 3, ... 1 stars. Lets say there are 100's 5 star rating, 70 * 4 star, 50 * 3 star, 30 * 2 and 20 * 1 star rating. So you can determine rating by:

> sum of rating / total rating

So it will be (100 * 5 + 70 * 4 + 50 * 3 + 30 * 2 + 20 * 1) / 100 + 70 + 50 + 30 + 20

So the final rating will be: **3.74**

To get the width percentage: (3.74 * 100) / 5 = 74.8

Here 5 refers to total number of stars, here I am assuming that rating will be based on the scale of 5.

For rendering you will need different HTML and CSS.

Code source: https://codepen.io/Bluetidepro/pen/GkpEa

```css
      .star-ratings-css {
            unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
            color: #c5c5c5;
            font-size: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
        }

        .star-ratings-css-top {
            color: #e7711b;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .star-ratings-css-bottom {
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .star-ratings-sprite {
            background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2605/star-rating-sprite.png") repeat-x;
            font-size: 0;
            height: 21px;
            line-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-indent: -999em;
            width: 110px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .star-ratings-sprite-rating {
            background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2605/star-rating-sprite.png") repeat-x;
            background-position: 0 100%;
            float: left;
            height: 21px;
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
    <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 74.8%">
        <span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
    <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
</div>
```

You need to pass width from your view and in the HTML, you need to access it. 
`<div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: {{ width }}%">`. I tried these code snippet, working for me and should work for you as well :)

Comment: Thanks for your big help, I greatly appreciate it ! For the rendering, it's working almost perfectly but I can't pass the width from the view to the template. I define width in the view, pass it to the template and use ```style="width: {{ width }}%"``` to get it but that doesn't take the value of width into account and always displays 5 stars. It's strange, I've mad researchs about how to use variable in html attribute and that should work

Comment: And for the recording, I don't understand how to record the value to my database. Sorry if I'm a complete noob but, usually, I always record objects to the database using a form. Here I guess I have to replace the ```"// some processing"``` part of your code by something that will change the attribute ```note``` of my ```avis``` model by the rating. But I don't know how to access the instance of the model in the js code since the instance is created in the view with the values from the form. Can I ask you a little more help for this please ?

Comment: what is the width you providing from the view ? and check in your browser inspector as well. that `// some processing` part is for Javascript in case you want to perform some action if the event is successful. You need to create a view for the ajax part in which you can create new entries.

Comment: My views is simply ```def profil(request, id):
    chef = get_object_or_404(Chef, id=id)
    width = chef.rating*20
    return render(request, 'inscription/profil_chef.html', locals())``` I've also tried with ```width = 80``` and that doesn't work either. In my inspector, it's correctly written ```width: 80%``` so I don't see why it displays 5 stars and not 4. I don't understand what you mean by creating a view for the ajax part, I have already a view for this functionality

Comment: I meant for storing the likes, thats good if it is working, but I don't understand why the width is not working for you. Can you check if you have any css trying to affect that element?

Comment: I solved it, the width has to be a string and the % has to be in the string and not in the template : ```width = str(chef.rating*20) + "%"```. However, I'm still not able to store the likes, what do you mean by creating a view for the ajax part in which I can create new entries ? If I understand well I have to put in the 'url' attribute of ajax a url to a view in which I can store the ratings ? And I pass the dictionary ```data``` as argument to this view to get the rating ?

Comment: yes, you have to enter some valid url in `url: "some_url"` and and url will point to some view, in that view you can store the rating by accessing `request.POST.get('rating'). You haven't added your view so I am not sure if you already did that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still blocked... the view in the url part of ajax is never called, and I don't know how I can get the ```avis``` id in the template to pass it to the view since the avis object has not been created yet in the template. I've edited my post with my code at the moment. So basically, in the template I click on the stars to have the rating, I fill in the form, I submit the form, that redirects me to my view and an error is raised since there is no rating in the form. And the second view for recording the rating is never called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205388/discussion-between-nalin-dobhal-and-julien-mertz).